Comparison in Kotlin
I'm a beginner in Kotlin and I'm trying to learn about comparison so i wrote this code:
fun main() {
    val laptops = listOf(
        laptop(2020, 8, 1000),
        laptop(2022, 4, 800),
        laptop(2021, 16, 600),
    )

    laptops
        .sortedWith(compareBy<laptop> { it.year }.thenBy { it.price })
        .forEach(::println)
}

data class laptop(var year: Int, var ram: Int, var price: Int)

I assumed that it will sort them first by the year then by the price but when the code was executed it sorts them only according to the year. But I did not get why?
In the above code I expected to get two results.

thenBy doesn’t mean start sorting the entire list by the new criteria. It defines a secondary way to compare items when they have a tie under the first way of comparing them. None of your items have a tie for same value of year.

Ah OK thank u so much got it

Your test case is incomplete, since the laptop objects in your input data all have different year values, so you never get to see the secondary sorting. Adding one with the same year as another, e.g.
val laptops = listOf(
    laptop(2022, 4, 1000),
    laptop(2020, 8, 1000),
    laptop(2022, 4, 800),
    laptop(2021, 16, 600),
)

shows the expected result.

Thank u got it :)
